# Integrating CSS Into a WP Function Call

Tags: php, functions, css, options, views

Below is a code I use to display post views.  It is integrated with an options panel which allows users to choose whether to display it.

I would like to integrate the div class .postviews directly into the code.  I would like to do this because it incorporates a blue background and if the views are not displayed, that blue background still gets displayed.

```
<div class="postviews">
<?php $options = get_option('to_post_views');
if( $options == 'Yes' ) { echo getPostViews( get_the_ID() );
} ?>
</div>
```

If you view [this page](http://themeforward.com/demo2/2012/10/03/video/), views are currently being displayed where it says "58 views."

Comment: Even though answered, given the nature of the actual topic of the question, I'd still say this ought to be closed as *off-topic*.

Comment: I disagree, I think it should be closed because it's not really a question, and its not obvious what is needed to answer it.

Comment: This is basically just a PHP question.

Comment: Yeah, to hell with PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact, that the conditional is based on a WordPress option, this is pure PHP, but anyhoo:

```
<?php
    $show_views = get_option( 'to_post_views' );

    if ( 'Yes' === $show_views ) {
        echo '<div class="postviews">' .
            getPostViews( get_the_ID() ) .
            '</div>';
    }
?>
```